# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am currently writing an application that displays some graphical user information in pie charts. To parse the pie chart data I return this to an JSON array

```
$result = array(); while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) { $row[] = $series[0]; $row[] = $obj[0]; $row1[] = $series[1]; $row1[] = $obj[1]; $row2[] = $series[2]; $row2[] = $obj[2]; $row3[] = $series[3]; $row3[] = $obj[3]; $row4[] = $series[4]; $row4[]
= $obj[4]; $row5[] = $series[5]; $row5[] = $obj[5]; } array_push($result,$row); array_push($result,$row1); array_push($result,$row2); array_push($result,$row3); array_push($result,$row4); array_push($result,$row5); echo json_encode($result);}else{ //
Fallback behaviour goes here echo "No Data\n"; }
```

This pushes all my result to the array, I am then using Highcharts to display this information in the chart,

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
        options.series[$x].data = json;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
     }
});
```

When I run a Chrome inspector on this it returns the error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

This is then throwing some of my testing of as it is giving a false positive failure. The information is returning correctly so there does not seem to be an issue with the code.

Is there anyway to get rid of this error.

Thanks,

Comment: You cant "get rid of it", `options.series[$x]` is not defined in this case and its not chromes fault. I dont know Highcharts but maybe you mixed up PHP and JS a bit cause you callet your variable `$x` instead of `x`?

Comment: Could you provide `options` object state before your $.getJSON call? We're assuming that `options.series` is not correctly defined.

Comment: @TomDoodler you look to be correct. Even changing to x has the same issue.

Comment: @slomek the line throwing the error is `options.series[$x].data = json;` the options look to be fine.

Comment: Adding series data where `option.series` call, `                   series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: ['Products'],
                        data: []
                    }]`

Comment: why $x ? simply iterate with x. Also check in options object properly defined. better if you post a fiddle with your code using static data/json

Comment: The variable naming is confusing, but not related to the issue

Comment: @Dave this is for series of data the url is then a parametized URL such as [link] http://localhost/index.php?user=Matt this saves us creating a thousand pages and also having a single page. Context is everything.

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi as  Tom mentioned this is php variable which has been carried across, using standard js variable naming doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Not sure why that was directed at me, I was responding to the hoopla regarding the variable name.

Comment: Why you initialise chart in each interation of loop (for) ? How your options variable and json looks like ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan very true, the chart should be outside the loop. The data is returning correctly such as `[[series, value], [series1, value1]]` so the data looks fine.